# How do i retrieve the "Parse Response" object if the request is successful and then use the object in my viewmodel class?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2

```
public ParseResponse getParseResponseObj(ParseRequest req){
   this.parseResponse =  getParseResponse(req);
    return this.parseResponse;
}

private ParseResponse getParseResponse(ParseRequest request){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

      final String BASE_URL = "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/";
      OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();
      httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

      Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        InfermedicaClient infermedicaClient = retrofit.create(InfermedicaClient.class);
    //final MutableLiveData<ParseResponse> resp = new MutableLiveData<>();
    //parseResponse = new ParseResponse();
    Call<ParseResponse> call = infermedicaClient.parseUserInput(Constants.APP_ID,Constants.APP_KEY,request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ParseResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ParseResponse> call, Response<ParseResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                 parseResponse = response.body();
             }
            Log.v("ParseReq Success" , response.message());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ParseResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.v("ParseReq Success" , t.getMessage());


        }
    });


    return parseResponse;
}
```

How do i retrieve the parse response object from a successful request and then use it in my viewmodel class.Also this request happens only once so, i didn't use livedata,also i am only using the response object in the viewmodel;am not displaying it to the user.i'm getting a null value even though the response from the server is ok.the getParseResponseObj is the method i call from the viewmodel!.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked out the issue,
 my response object did not match the response the server was returning so **gson** was not serializing the data correctly.